# Not using a variable for <-

Tags: haskell

This code obviously works

```
import Data.Char

main = do
  content <- readFile "in.txt"
  writeFile "out.txt" (map toUpper content)
```

Why this one doesn't?

```
import Data.Char

main = do
  writeFile "out.txt" (map toUpper $ <- readFile "in.txt")
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because this is not how `<-` is defined. It translates to

```
readFile "in.txt" >>= \content ->
writeFile "out.txt" (map toUpper content)
```

You could use `=<<` instead:

```
writeFile "out.txt" . map toUpper =<< readFile "in.txt"
```

Answer (score 16):

First, `<-` is not an operator. It's a special syntax element that requires a *pattern* on the left side.

Second, if it were an infix operator, `$ <-` would not work, as you cannot have two infix operators next to each other.

Answer (score 6):

The `<-` "extracts" a value from a monadic container.  `IO` is a monad, and so it can be used to extract a value from an `IO` action.  However, the syntax of Haskell says that you *must* bind it to a name before using it.  In actuality, the `<-` isn't an operator at all, but syntactic sugar for the `>>=` operator (pronounced "bind").  So when you write

```
main = do
    contents <- readFile "in.txt"
    writeFile "out.txt" (map toUpper contents)
```

It gets turned into

```
main = readFile "in.txt" >>= (\contents -> writeFile "out.txt" (map toUpper contents))
```

Now, imagine if you had a lot more statements in `main`.  Maybe you extracted several values with `<-`, and some of the expressions used more than one of those values at a time.  You could definitely write the "desugared" version, but it would start getting very, very difficult.  The do-notation simplifies this and makes the compiler take care of it for you.

Answer (score 3):

you can to write it as follows

```
readFile "in.txt" >>= writeFile "out.txt" . map toUpper
```

Comment: Or `map toUpper <$> readFile "in.txt" >>= writeFile "out.txt"`. However I think the OP wanted an explanation and not a mere solution